# How do i store a group containing more users in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL i have a table for users. On my website i want people be able to make groups consisting of 2 or more users, but i have no idea how to store that. People can be a part of multiple groups at the same time. If i'd make a table `groups`, how could i store it's members in that table?

Answer (score 1):

You would have a table `groups` and one called `userGroups`.  These would look like:

```
create table groups (
    groupId int auto_increment primary key,
    groupName varchar(255)
);

create table userGroups (
    userGroupId int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int not null,
    groupId int not null,
    foreign key (userId) references users(userId),
    foreign key (groupId) references groups(groupId)
);
```

Comment: I'd suggest a unique constraint on the FKs if you're going the surrogate key.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is called a many-to-many relationship, and it requires a third table:

- UserTable: UserID (unique), UserName, etc.
- GroupTable: GroupID (unique), GroupName, etc.
- UserGroups: UserGroupID (unique), UserID, GroupID

Answer (score 0):

With a third table holding the primary key(pk)) of a group and a pk  of a person. These columns are the pk of the table. You can have other to 
Columns  too, e.g. date joined or whatever. You have one row in this table per person/group.

It's a common concept/pattern so make sure you learn and understand it.